# How to send message from server to client using SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I send something from server to clients using SignalR?
I created send method like bellow:

```
    public async void SendData(string data)
    {
       await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", data);
    }
```

My javascript:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/somemsg").build();


connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("responeHistory").appendChild(li);
    li.textContent = `${message}`;
});
```

In my case I receive error that Clients 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: I your connection at least connected? Can you set a breakpoint inside SendData()? If so, does it hit the method?

Answer (score 0):

If you're registering SignalR in service collection, you can just inject
IHubConnectionContext, here's an example from ms docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr#getting-the-signalr-context-so-that-the-stockticker-class-can-broadcast-to-clients